# ERROR executing python script with nohup after a while: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Tags: python, linux, selenium, nohup

I am trying to run a bot on my `linux`server that checks prices, I used `selenium` in my `python` script. I run it with `nohup` in the backgroun but after a while I encounter the folowing error:

```
File "selenium_amazon.py", line 68, in <module>
    isProduct()
  File "selenium_amazon.py", line 63, in isProduct()
  File "selenium_amazon.py", line 22, in Product_functie
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "button"))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Also i can't find the file `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dis_packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py` on my server.

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem!

execute your command( `nohup python3 -u main.py` > out.out & )
normally , **open a second terminal** and execute the command `screen -r` ( this will attach in the process the screen that selenium needs) . After that close the both terminal and check the size file from your logs. ( I use snowflake to connect in my terminals )

Answer (score 0):

An implicit wait tells WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find any element (or elements) not immediately available. The default setting is 0 (zero). Once set, the implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
myDynamicElement = driver.find_element_by_id("myDynamicElement")
```

[Use this link for more details](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#implicit-waits)